# Android RadioButton RTL Layout not applying padding

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to use RTL in my layout.

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:text="String"
            android:textColor="color"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
```

LTR Layout:

[image]

RTL Layout:

[image]

In the RTL Layout the right padding is not being applied to the radio button and the text goes to the left side. Is there any option to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

To have the text near radio button, you can put the text alignment to start of the view.
`android:textAlignment="viewStart"`

To have the radio button respect margins, you can use `drawableStart`

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatRadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"


         android:button="@null"
         android:drawableStart="@drawable/radio_button"
         android:drawablePadding="11dp"
         android:padding="18dp"
         android:textAlignment="viewStart"


        android:text="Radio Button Text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        />
```

Comment: This works for the text. But what can I do for the button padding?  You could see in the second image that the radio button is not talking 18dp right padding.